# How do I add a clearing DIV to the bottom of a region?

Tags: 6, blocks, theming

In the eternal mission to care about Internet Explorer, I have a template region which needs a clearing `<div<`, since I think that ":after" and "overflow:hidden" tricks don't work so well in IE. (I'm currently not able to test this as I'm on a Mac without a virtual machine.)

Is there any region preprocess trick, or anything equally clean, in order of adding a clearing `<div>`? I'd prefer not to use Javascript, or add an entire block for this purpose, if it is possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would find a common class for your region(s), and add in the [clearfix](http://www.yuiblog.com/blog/2010/09/27/clearfix-reloaded-overflowhidden-demystified/) rules.  With kosher HTML and CSS, I don't recall the last time this didn't work in IE for me.

Answer (score 1):

Drupal already has built in clearfix classes you can use. For Drupal 7, use `clearfix`. For Drupal 6, I believe it is `clear-block`.

Comment: Both of those are slightly outdated versions.  The link in my answer has the most recent incarnation.